# add 10 days to a datepicker value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got a datepicker value like this

```
`Fri Mar 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
```

I want to add 60 days to it

so after adding that my value looks like this

```
`Fri Apr 29 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
```

I have searched stackoverflow but I cant get a solution for this format

Answer (score 0):

```
addDays(date, days) {
    const result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but I only get a value like this 1619980200000

Comment: I want a value like this `Fri Mar 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: In this solution when you add it changes format. I am trying to patch that value to a formcontrol so I need the same format so that I can patch

Answer (score 0):

with date api: `new Date().getDate() + 60`

with momentjs: `moment().add(60, "day")`

more info: https://stackblitz.com/edit/momentjs-format-date-3gguqn